# I keep getting this error each time i compile and run : main.cpp:15:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error each time i compile and run : main.cpp:15:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string paragraph;
    cin>>paragraph;

    int wordsCount;
    int pSize = paragraph.length();

    for (int i = 0; i<pSize ; i++)
    {
        if (paragraph[i] == " ") {
            wordsCount++;
        }
    }




    cout << pSize << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`" "` is a string literal. This is an immutable character array and is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array in this case.

You should `' '` (character surrounded by single quote, not double quote) to represent one character.

Also the variable `wordsCount` is incremented without being initialized. You should initialize first before doing calculation with its value.

What is done in the `for` loop is actually not used in this case, so you can remove the loop like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string paragraph;
    cin>>paragraph;

    int pSize = paragraph.length();

    cout << pSize << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you dude <3